# How to remove Bitmap from ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, arraylist, parcelable

I have a class called PlayerList, in in that class i have an ArrayList defined like this :

```
private ArrayList<Bitmap> images = new ArrayList<Bitmap>();
```

Now, an ArrayList remove method can exept 2 arguments, an index and an Object.

I'm trying to remove a Bitmap from the array by sending the Bitmap to it. The thing is the bit map is made of the same image but the instace of the Bitmap i saved in the array is not the same i'm trying to find, when i print the ArrayList to console i see new names all the time, stuff like :

```
[android.graphics.Bitmap@44ea2d48, android.graphics.Bitmap@44ea2e20]
```

Could this be related? and while wer're at it, The class implements `Parcelable` so the data being read/writen back and forth, that can't be too healthy too, right?

Am i missing a generic problem or it's code specific and i should publish my code?

My problem here basiclly is when i try to remove the Bitmap, it allways removes the wrong item in the arraylist, always 1 before the 1 i need

Comment: If the instance is different, unless you create equals/hash methods that check the image *content*, you're out of luck. You could use a different mechanism, like giving them an ID or referring to them by name, etc. as well.

Comment: And if i'll use Drawable instead? will that work?

Comment: It's not about what interface your `Bitmap` class implements. The `remove` method uses `equals` method of your `Bitmap` object to locate and remove it from the list. So, unless you properly implement the `equals` method in the `Bitmap` class you can not expect `ArrayList.remove` method to remove the right object.

Comment: What about switching an ArrayList for a Map and using a key to identify the images?

Comment: Yeah that's probably what i'll do. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you have a handle to the `BitMap's` hash code or a like key based on which it is stored, you can't remove a desired one from the list. If you just want to depend on `BitMap` stored, you need to traverse through the list and parse elements to find desired bitmap. Again you need a hascode to identify if the `BitMap` you are parsing is what you are looking for. Meaning you need to maintain a list of `hashcode's` for each of the `BitMap` stored. Alternatively use `HashMap` over `List` that allows to store a `key` against a `BitMap` being stored. And you can process your requirement based on the `key` and use it whenever required to remove a `BitMap` from the `HashMap` table.

```
HashMap<String, BitMap> myBitMaps = ... // construct as you desire.
...
if ( condition satisfied on key ) {
  myBitMaps.remove( keyObject );
  // process further
}
```